# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined" at Tempus Dominus datetimepicker?

Tags: javascript, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I have used [Tempus Dominus Bootstrap 4](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) for my date time picker. When user put invalid value on the input and focus out(click outside of the component), it gets `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'format' of undefined`.

[image]

But, expected behavior is like this: https://i.imgur.com/MWgrBkB.mp4

How to fix the error?

**[My Demo](https://codepen.io/lr_73/pen/MWgGwxb)**

**Update:** Issue wasn't generated for someone. **Here is the way of generating the issue:** https://i.imgur.com/F0BpgZQ.mp4

Comment: Works fine in my end.

Comment: working fine in my end too.

Comment: Here is the video of getting issue for my codepen demo: https://i.imgur.com/F0BpgZQ.mp4

Comment: I have found an open github issue regarding this too: https://github.com/tempusdominus/bootstrap-4/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('.date-time-picker').datetimepicker
    ({
    format:'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm',
    icons:{
    time:'far fa-clock'
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody face a similar issue take into account if you are initializing, set option, or get option from the datepicker:

https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/Options/

Note Initialize options as `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({ sideBySide: true, debug: true })`

Note To set options use `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('sideBySide', true)`

Note To get option value use `$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('sideBySide')`

In my case I was initializing the defaults icons in a common js file and initializing again (Initialize option) in a local js of the page. 
In the local js set options method should be used.

Answer (score 0):

this Fix from github , it error from  function _getLastPickedDate()
in file tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js
step to fix

1. unmin file  tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js
2. find _getLastPickedDate()
3. replace with `var lastDate = this._dates[this._getLastPickedDateIndex()]; if (typeof lastDate == "undefined" || lastDate == null) { lastDate = this.getMoment(); } return lastDate;`

cr. github